# WCF + Json = wrong serialization

Tags: asp.net, jquery, wcf, json

Why this WCF 3.5 method

```
[ServiceContract]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class Json
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public string Upper(string text)
    {
        return text.ToUpper();
    }
}
```

returns `{"d":"TEXT"}` ?

It should returns `{"TEXT"}`

I'm calling using jQuery.

```
    $("#upper").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Json.svc/Upper?text="+$("#input1").val(),
            success: function(data) {
                $("#input1").val(data.d);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a security feature that has been added to the JSON serialization in .NET 3.5. It's a container object, so instead of, say, `results[0]`, you would just say `results.d[0]`. Read [this article](http://encosia.com/2009/02/10/a-breaking-change-between-versions-of-aspnet-ajax/) for more information.

Comment: Nice Brandon, but can I remove/disable this?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. But why would you want to disable this? It's a big security risk if you disable it. As the article says, it's worth the effort now to deal with the "d" container object.

Comment: Also, `{'Text'}` isn't valid JSON.  In jQuery 1.4.x, that will cause trouble, so the .d is nice to have for that reason too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are using `<enableWebScript/>` in your behavior config, replace that with `<webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"/>` and you will get json without the root "d" and without the "__type" props.

However, I've only tested this in 4.0

I also don't use any attributes in code.

Comment: This doesn't work, you still have to have bodystyle = webmessagebodystyle.wrappedrequest, which includes the "d" and "___type". If you change it to Bare, you get an error that Bare is not supported for WebScriptEnablingBehavior.

Comment: I can assure you it does work, but I should have clarified that I only tested in 4.0, and I don't use any attributes in code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the [BodyStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webgetattribute.bodystyle.aspx) property of your [WebGet] Attribute so that responses aren't wrapped?

Comment: Yes, but I get this exception "The body style 'Wrapped' is not supported by 'WebScriptEnablingBehavior'. Change the body style to be 'WrappedRequest'."
or
"The body style 'Bare' is not supported by 'WebScriptEnablingBehavior'. Change the body style to be 'WrappedRequest'."

Comment: If you're using webScriptEnablingBehavior then yes, it can cause issues. Is there a particular reason you want that instead of webHttpBehavior?

Also, have you checked this: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/324917.aspx

Comment: No particular reason. I did yesterday like your link, but I think my web.config was wrong, so I got another tutorial on bing. That's tutorial are working fine, the only issue is this d "property".

Comment: If you don't use webscriptenable behavior then it returns a 400 error when you try to view the call in a web browser.