# Signed policy returned from dotnet server method includes "d"

Tags: .net, json, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

I recently purchased FineUploader for S3 and I'm having trouble getting it to accept my policy and signature from my signature.endpoint.  The json that is returned includes the policy and signature data but it's embedded in the all encompassing "d" property (MS's way of "protecting" me from cross scripting attacks).  I'm trying to pull off a direct browser upload  and I read the blog entry that includes samples for python, java, and php but I'm going to host this in DotNetNuke.  I believe my code is fine, the issue is the client side callback can't read the json because of the d.  No matter how I try to return the html (string, object, serialized object) it always includes the "d" like so:

{"**d**":"{\"policy\":\"POLICYDATA\",\"signature\":\"SIGNATUREDATA\"}"}

Has anyone successfully returned json from a .NET server side method to the Fine Uploader callback?

```
<div id="fineuploader-s3"></div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/custom.fineuploader-4.0.3.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#fineuploader-s3').fineUploaderS3({
            request: {
                endpoint: "bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com",
                accessKey: "MYACCESSKEY"
            },
            template: "simple-previews-template",
            signature: {
                endpoint: "/aws.asmx/sig"
            },
            uploadSuccess: {
                endpoint: "somefile.html"
            },
            iframeSupport: {
                localBlankPagePath: "success.html"
            }
        })
            // Enable the "view" link in the UI that allows the file to be downloaded/viewed
            .on('complete', function (event, id, name, response) {
                var $fileEl = $(this).fineUploaderS3("getItemByFileId", id),
                    $viewBtn = $fileEl.find(".view-btn");

                if (response.success) {
                    $viewBtn.show();
                    $viewBtn.attr("href", response.tempLink);
                }
            });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You're right, it looks like this is a something that .NET forces into the response before it is returned to the client.  I don't have very much experience dealing with .NET, so I'm not sure if there is a way to turn this off.  You may want to spend some time determining if you can prevent .NET from modifying the response like this.  Another option would be to [open up an enhancement request in Fine Uploader's issue tracker](http://bit.ly/1hbFS8a), asking for FU to be aware of and handle this natively. It wouldn't be the first time Fine Uploader had to work around Microsoft-related silliness.

Comment: ...by the way, it seems uncommon for a .NET app to utilize AWS.  Why aren't you using Azure?

Comment: This answer might be worth a look if you want to turn this off (and turning it off would definitely be my first choice): http://stackoverflow.com/a/6231552/486979

Comment: Another good article here which should instruct you how to prevent the d property from wrapping your response: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx.

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to answer Ray.  I'm going to look into these articles in the next day or so.  Will post my results.  Thanks again.

Comment: Any results @Bristol.NET?